# withCredentials not working HttpClient in Anuglar 5

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I want to send http session cookies to the server from Angular5 project 
I found I must set  withCredentials  to true But It does not work at all 
 This is the intercept of HttpClient

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
       Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       req = req.clone({
         setHeaders: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
             },
          withCredentials:true

         });

       return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: any response from the server? how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The server try to find the user session when the user call the server after 
 login 
If I test it outside Angular its works from browser or postman for example

Comment: try and clone the request to a new variable like this,   const clonedReq = req.clone({...

Comment: please share complete class code for your `intercept` method

Comment: and `AppModule` class